# Terminate a loop with specific characters

Tags: c++, loops

I want to write a program that will terminate a loop with a specific character such as "Q" or "//" but can't seem to figure it out. here is the specifics

> "A program that will compute the average of a set of decimal
>   numbers provided by the user. The program will ask the user to enter
>   numbers one at a time, and when the user enters q it stops and spits out the sum"

But this requires the user to enter in integers and if I enter a "Q" or "//" the program breaks and spits out junk. How do I do this?

The problem im running into is how to do this without asking for two different inputs

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//variables
double avg, num;
char q;

int main()
{
    double sum = 0;
    int count1 = 0;
    while (q != 'q') {
        cout << "Enter a number" << endl;
        cin >> num;
        cin >> q;
        sum += num;
        count1 += 1;
    }
    avg = sum / count1;
    cout << "Sum: " << sum << endl;
    cout << "Count: " << count1 << endl;
    cout << "Average: " << avg << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show your code/efforts you have done so far.

Comment: Show us what you have tried, by enclosing a [MCVE]. The whole point of the assignment is to see if you can actually do it, and not resort to posting on SO in the hope someone else will write the code for you.

Comment: I added my work, i didnt at first because I didnt have much or know where to begin. My point is not to get the answer either, its to get guidance which is exactly why I asked where do i start

Comment: What course notes are you lacking to come up with the above? You have a loop there clearly, but the `if` logic is mysteriously not understood. You are not asking the lecturer on the questions needed or the lecturer is being blatantly ignorant in not teaching the proper fundamentals of programming!

Comment: its a online class and im having trouble understanding which is why i came here, can u give me any help?

Comment: because the point of the program is to input integers and collect the sum but when the user type "Q'' the program stops and spits out the sum

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your assignment is really what you describe, then you will need to read a string, and then convert to double.

Something like this will work:

```
std::string s;
std::cin >> s;
if (s == "Q" || s == "//") { ... do stuff ... }
else
{
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    double d;
    if (!(ss >> d))
    {
        std::cout << s << " doesn't appear to be a number..." << std::endl;
    }
    ... do whatever with d ... 
}
```

I'm not writing the code for you, just providing some snippets to help you along.

Comment: thank you, my problem was not knowing how to complete this without asking for two different inputs this def helps!

Comment: While std::stringstream is a nice generic solution, [std::stod](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) is more concise.